# Erlang: How to make an UDP packet

Tags: erlang, udp, packets

How can I make an UDP packet in Erlang?
The backbone of packets:

byte 0-3: SAMP
byte 4: 127
byte 5: 0
byte 6: 0
byte 7: 1
byte 8: first byte of '7777'
byte 9: second byte of '7777'
byte 10: 'i'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<<SAMP:32,127,0,0,1,7777:16,$i>>
```

assuming `SAMP` is a variable and `'i'` is the character "i".

Look at [Bit Syntax Expressions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id77874) for the syntax of binaries and [Bit Syntax Examples](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) for more examples. The second one has an example of writing an IP packet in one bit syntax expression/pattern, which is very neat.